# Used Dobsonian reflector won't focus

Tags: lenses

I have collimated my 10" reflector telescope both manually, and later with a lazer, I have placed my eyepieces in the focusing tube, and rolled in, and out with no ability to resolve my target.  Can someone give me an idea of what, besides bad collimation, could be going wrong?

Comment: I think the question is better suited to Astronomy.SE: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How far away is your target? Astronomical objects are effectively at infinity. The focusing tube may not allow enough adjustment if you aim too close.

Comment: Try not letting the eyepiece go all the way into the focuser.

Answer (score 1):

If poor collimation and mirror conditions are ruled out, then it could be a focuser issue, where it doesn't allow eyepiece to be at a necessary distance to achieve focus.

Did you put on or remove any extension tube during collimation?

Also worth checking if you over tightened the focuser tension adjustment, which can prevent it from moving.